# Selection from a list of active and archived documents

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have two applications. The first one have documents with a number and title. The second one have documents to selected the number from the first one als multiple value.
Now a few documents from the first one were archived. Now the number in the second one must stay. If I wanted to update the numbers the archived one must be selected.
So I cannot work with a view because the archived documents are no longer in notes. A list is perhaps too long because we have over 2300 active Documents and with the archived over 10000 numbers.
I don't have an idea.

Comment: There's really not enough info here to give you an answer, so I'm voting to close - but I want to tell you what kind of questions I would ask to get enough info . What kind of archiving system is this? If the documents are no longer in a view, and as you said "no longer in notes", where are they? Is there an API that you can call to find them? Does the archiving system create a log in Notes, or anywhere else that you can read with code? Can the archiving system be programmed to leave "stubs" or to run an agent for you after archiving each document?

Comment: The archive is a DVD. The data cannot used.
I found a solution. No good, but works for the time. Only active number can put to the field. All numbers in the field can be deleted.